# Open the legacy Control Panel "File Associations" (or s.th. similar) in Win10

Tags: windows-10, file-association

Is it possible to open the legacy Control Panel "File Associations" in Windows 10? I'm talking about this one:

[image]

I tired several options but it just refers me to the "new" settings page, which in turn only allows me to add shop-apps to certain file associations (and not any local installed exe):

[image]

The only way I found is to create an (empty) file with the right extension and then in file explorer go through the right click "open with" option. Is the right click option only way now that is supported via GUI?

Note:  I already know I can change it via cmd through `assoc`, but I'm actually looking for a better GUI solution here. I have a question in regards to a CLI approach [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1684151/changing-file-associations-via-assoc).

Comment: Use Window File Explorer, right click on the file, choose Open With and then when you choose the APP, there should be a selection to say Always use this app. Try that - it should work.

Comment: @John thx, that's what I described with "The only way I found..." that was through the explorer, sorry, I will add it to make it clear.

Comment: In the search bar type File Associations, the choose first result

Comment: @Moab thanks, but that only lets me choose additional apps form the app store (or apps already installed from the app store). Not any exe that resides on the system (the second screenshot I posted)

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with 1803 that feature was removed entirely, with any access to the old feature redirected to the new interface, so to answer directly: No, the interface no longer exists in current Windows 10.

I can't remember where I first saw it suggested, but I was directed to this ancient 3rd party app that gives a similar feature set to the original Win7 interface and still works well under Windows 10:

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

Alternatively, it may be possible to hand-port the binaries over from an older installation, but I suspect you would then also have to reverse-engineer all of the CLSID redirections to allow it to work.

Comment: Ah, Nirsoft again... I dread the day when he stops developing his tools... I'll give it a try and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Use the
[Default Programs Editor](https://defaultprogramseditor.com/)
for fixing file association settings in Windows,
including context menu items, icons, and descriptions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, in what way is it better/different then the Nirsoft Tool? I noticed the last update was over 3,5 years ago while Nirsoft is still being developed. Would you suggest using it over Nirsoft?

Comment: Both programs are different and can be complementary. Default Programs Editor seems to have more sophisticated actions.