# Changing File Associations via assoc

Tags: windows-10, command-line, file-association

I'm trying to change file associations via `assoc` (CLI), but I can't get `assoc` to show me the current default program:

```
assoc .txt
```

Returns: `.txt=txtfile`

and

```
assoc txtfile
```

Returns: `txtfile=Text Document`

Is `assoc` still the right command line tool for this job in Windows 10? Searching the Internet I got tons of options (`ftype`, `SetUserFTA`, `dism.exe`, GPO, etc.) and before trying them all out one by one I thought asking some expert advice first.

Note, I'm mainly talking about .exe associations not about the Windows apps / store apps, although I might have to deal with apps as well in the future (especially concerning MS Office).

Comment: Go here and scroll down on the page>>>https://www.maketecheasier.com/change-file-associations-windows10/

Comment: @Moab Thanks that's still another option (ftype). Do you prefere using it over SetUSerFTA, dism.exe, etc.?

Comment: I just googled it, so i have no preference. See my comment in you other question.

Comment: @Moab yeah that's exactly what I did, google just came up with so many different options, I though I post a question first

Comment: `Assoc` is part of a two command thing. The other part being `FType`. `Assoc` maps a extension to a filetype. `FType` maps a program to a filetype's *Open* verb. **NB:** This is the type of association from Win 3.1. It is still used by 99% of programs. But the other 1% uses newer (that's in the last 30 years) methods that `Assoc`/`FType` don't understand.

Comment: @user1292580 that's what I was looking for! Complete forgot about that it goes together with FType. thank you!